# Is browser Date#toString time zone reliable

Tags: browser, timezone

Most browsers can display some kind of timezone information: for example  `new Date().toString()` returns `"Fri Apr 07 2017 02:20:12 GMT-0500 (CDT)"`.

However I see many solutions do not use this at all, instead try to guess timezone using several methods.

If `new Date().toString()` does return some timezone information, will that  be correct? Or can browsers also return wrong info too?

Comment: I guess if that's not the case, then browser probably has to guess the time zone, and is unable to get it directly from OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in parenthesis is not defined in the ECMAScript specification.  It is up to each implementation to decide what they want to show there.  Thus, the value is only as reliable as the implementation makes it.  One cannot state anything in general, other than to expect inconsistent results.

That said, many modern implementations take their values from the same source data, which is [the Unicode CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org/), usually by way of [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).  Those that do will usually give a fully localized text value, such as `"Eastern Daylight Time"` in English.   (Not just `"EDT"`)